# Mutate with column value >0

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column ReactionTime using Trigger and Imageonset columns.
For the following mutation I want to use only Trigger values > 0. How can I do that?

```
data <- data %>% mutate(ReactionTime = Trigger-Imageonset)
```

My data looks like this:

```
Subject Imageonset Trigger
1       25438.889   0.000
1       1251.783    0.000
1       1304.119    1308.677
1       1331.455    1334.053
1       1351.956    0.000
1       1374.707    1378.588
1       1400.092    0.000
1       1422.577    1426.804
1       1450.037    1453.035
...
```

I want get this result:

```
Subject Imageonset Trigger   ReactionTime
1       25438.889   0.000    0
1       1251.783    0.000    0
1       1304.119    1308.677 4.558
1       1331.455    1334.053 2.608
1       1351.956    0.000    0
1       1374.707    1378.588 3.881
1       1400.092    0.000    0
1       1422.577    1426.804 1.227
1       1450.037    1453.035 2.998
...
```

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas:

```
# use ifelse
data <- data %>% mutate(ReactionTime = ifelse(Trigger > 0, Trigger-Imageonset, 0))

# use dplyr::if_else
data <- data %>% mutate(ReactionTime = if_else(Trigger > 0, Trigger-Imageonset, 0))

# use multiplication
data <- data %>% mutate(ReactionTime = Trigger-Imageonset * (Trigger > 0))

# use replace
data <- data %>% mutate(
  ReactionTime = Trigger-Imageonset,
  ReactionTime = replace(ReactionTime, Trigger == 0, 0)
)
```